# .net maui onplatform font size not working for iOS

Tags: ios, maui, font-size

I'm trying to use OnPlatform XAML option to get appropriate font sizes for different platforms. Code snippet below, values just samples; I've tried many different ones!

Android and UWP respond to whatever I set, but for iOS nothing ever changes. (And just as an aside, I can't change the font color on iOS either, but I'm less worried about that at the moment!)

Any hints anyone?

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RBStyle}" Content="Cy" VerticalOptions="Center" >
  <RadioButton.FontSize>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <On Platform="Android" Value="20"/>
          <On Platform="iOS" Value="10"/>
          <On Platform="UWP" Value="30"/>
      </OnPlatform>
  </RadioButton.FontSize>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: PS The style has no font data in it, just TextColor and Opacity options, which as stated, also don't work on iOS

Comment: You can accept the answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in .NET MAUI.

`FontAttributes` property doesn't work on iOS, too.

Fortunately, iOS supports using a `View` for the `Content` property of `RadioButton`, so you can apply a workaround like this.

`MainPage.xaml`

```xml
<RadioButton Content="Cy" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="MyRadioButton">
    <RadioButton.FontSize>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="20"/>
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="30"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </RadioButton.FontSize>
</RadioButton>
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
#if IOS
    MyRadioButton.Content = new Label
    {
        Text = "Cy",
        FontSize = 10
    };
#endif
}
```

---

If you want to track the issue status: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19081

Comment: Thank you! I should have realised this was the workaround as when I first started this project I did exactly what you suggest and used a view for the radiobutton content. However, I quickly discovered that the view didn't work on Android, in fact it crashed the emulator. I'm only now just resorting to conditional per-platform code. THis should work - annoying though!